# ImportError: No module named schedule?

Tags: python, pip, importerror, schedule

I am a beginner so bare with me but I keep getting the error "ImportError: No module named schedule" when I run the most basic code in VS code and it's really frustrating. I installed the latest version of python (3.11.5). I installed the latest version of pip and then I downloaded the pip schedule package.

When I run "pip show schedule" it says...

```
Name: schedule
Version: 1.2.0
Summary: Job scheduling for humans.
Home-page: https://github.com/dbader/schedule
Author: Daniel Bader
Author-email: mail@dbader.org
License: MIT
Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages
Requires:
Required-by:
```

This is the code I am trying to run in VS code.

```
import schedule
import time

def print_message():
    print("This message is printed every 5 seconds.")

# Schedule the print_message function to run every 5 seconds
schedule.every(5).seconds.do(print_message)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

The complete error I get is

```
[Running] python -u "/var/folders/84/clypl_nd5jx7_h2dv_qg7c_c0000gn/T/tempCodeRunnerFile.python"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/folders/84/clypl_nd5jx7_h2dv_qg7c_c0000gn/T/tempCodeRunnerFile.python", line 1, in <module>
    import schedule
ImportError: No module named schedule
```

I even tried adding this to the code and it still didn't work

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages")
import schedule
import time
```

This is the error I get

```
[Running] python -u "/var/folders/84/clypl_nd5jx7_h2dv_qg7c_c0000gn/T/tempCodeRunnerFile.python"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/folders/84/clypl_nd5jx7_h2dv_qg7c_c0000gn/T/tempCodeRunnerFile.python", line 3, in <module>
    import schedule
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/schedule/__init__.py", line 85
    def __init__(self) -> None:
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I listed everything I tried above.

Comment: You must have multiple python versions, and you pip installed the module on a different version to the one you then run your code with in VScode.

Comment: I installed python 3.11.5 and then I installed pip?

Comment: I thought when you install the latest version of python it deletes the old ones?

Comment: You thought wrong, you can have dozens of different pythons at the same time.

Comment: VScode lets you select which python interpreter to use, make sure you select the one you want...

Comment: On Mac, I run the command 'ls /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/' and it says I only have my current version installed 3.11

Comment: I set the interpreter to "3.11.5" but I still get the same error messages?

Comment: Could the problem be that I am using a Mac? My default Python -V is 2.7.16

Comment: I updated my macbook to macOS Monterey and now running 'python -V' returns 'zsh: command not found: python'. Now 'import schedule' code is returning '/bin/sh: python: command not found'. This leads me to believe that VScode was, and still is, using the python that is associated with running 'python -V' on my computer. There is now only one version of python installed on my system but vscode does not want to use it.

Comment: It is looking like the problem is with the extension "Code Runner". I need to find a way to get it to use python 3.11.5. Running the script as a "python file" makes it run no problem.

Comment: FINALLY FIXED THE PROBLEM! The issue is with Code Runner. But it's an easy fix. Open Code runner's Executor map settings.json --> find "python" and you'll notice that it says something like "python" == "python -u" --> change this to "python" == "python3" and the code should be running with the shortcuts in the Output window.

Cheers!